Conceptual question about trap levels in semiconductors and their occupancy
[Cross posted to material modeling stack exchange  as recommended in the comments, although I couldn't find the policies for that.]
Some fairly basic conceptual questions arose as I was doing some DFT and getting the DOS of an ionic semiconductor system with a defect.
When the system is globally neutral, the defect is in the $-2$ charge state. I call this the empty trap state. If I introduce a hole in the system (the overall atomic system now has a net charge of +1), I observe localization of the hole on the defect(*) which is now in the $-1$ charge state. I call this the filled trap state.
The confusion comes up when I produce a DOS for both filled and empty traps. In both cases, the geometry is the same and the only thing that changes is the presence of a localized hole on the defect (well, and some settings as to how the spin is handled which I will align later. It might explain some discrepancies between both but not answer the central question).

In the "empty trap" case (no hole, $-2$ charge state), we have a peak in the middle of the band gap. Integrating the DOS over this peak shows me that it corresponds to two electronic states.
In the "filled trap" case (trapped hole, $-1$ charge state), the peak is sightly shifted, which might be due to the Coulombic interaction induced by the trapped charge. All good. But what I don't understand, is that if I integrate the DOS over the trap state, I get this time only one state!
It seems that the addition of a hole made a trap state "disappear" in the band structure! (Looks like it re-distributed in the band edges). Now that doesn't match my understanding of band structures and their occupancy. Adding or subtracting charge carriers might shift some state levels, sure. It will definitely impact how those energy states are occupied. But I don't understand how it "deletes" some states. For me, the only difference when injecting a hole should be that a previously occupied state is now free (and potentially shifted), but it should not cease to exist.
Can anybody clarify this for me?
Bonus question: I was also surprised to see that a trap state with a $-2$ charge had its level in the middle of the bandgap, suggesting that it might be a trap for both electrons and holes, when simple coulombic considerations (as well as others) clearly suggest that it should preferentially be preferentially a hole trap.
(*)thanks to the use of appropriate self-interaction correction schemes for DFT
EDIT: it is worth noting that, in the ground state, the two electronic trap states are occupied by electrons when the trap is empty (no hole). They are just below the Fermi energy. When the hole is introduced, one of those states is occupied and moved back to the valence band. The remaining midgap trap state is now unoccupied by electrons (above Fermi energy)

If you don't get an answer here, consider to ask this on Matter Modeling SE. But please note the policies regarding cross-posting.

@TobiasFünke thanks, I will consider it, and I did hesitate when posting. But this felt more like a conceptual/theoretical level question, not hinging so much on the specificities of DFT (tho I could be wrong about that!)

Two thoughts. In silicon various trap levels move position in the gap depending on charge state. A trap that accepts an electron (say) will have degeneracy 2 because of spin up/down. Put an electron in it, then the degeneracy disappears since one spin state is occupied.

@JonCuster yes, energy level shifts with occupation make sense to me. However, the second part is what doesn't match my understanding. If there are 2 unoccupied degenerate states and you inject an electron, the degeneracy does not "disappear" afaik. Simply, one of the degenerate states is now occupied and the other still empty, but the states still exist (potentially shifted, which might mean they are not technically degenerate anymore, but there are still 2 states). The Existence of a state and its occupation are two distinct concepts. The DOS should reflect existence

What about the number of states below and above the gap in the two cases?

@GiorgioP-DoomsdayClockIsAt-90 In the empty case (-2): 130 states in the VB, 2 trap states mid-gap occupied by electrons. In the filled case (-1): 131 states in the VB, one empty trap state mid-gap. As I mentioned, one of the trap states appears to "move back to the valence band" when a hole gets trapped.

@GiorgioP-DoomsdayClockIsAt-90 NB: it occurs to me that it is not impossible that the additional valence state would be caused by the jellium correction applied by DFT to maintain overall charge neutrality. But I am not sure, I will look into it.

The fact that the state below the gap has the same energy as valence states of the intrinsic semiconductor does not mean it has become the same thing. It could still be different from the intrinsic semiconductor's valence band states, while looking indistinguishable on the diagram in question. This is because there is also a dense, periodic arrangement of lattice units, along which an added charge carrier can move without scattering, whereas the trap is at a fixed lattice site in space and if the charge carrier enters it, it scatters very often.
The trap state mentioned in the question didn't disappear really. It simply happened to have the same energy as the valence band, and no information about specific sites other than energy is depicted on the plot.
There are two conflicting statements in the question:

It seems that the addition of a hole made a trap state "disappear" in the band structure! (Looks like it re-distributed in the band edges)

and in the comments:

In the empty case (-2): 130 states in the VB, 2 trap states mid-gap occupied by electrons. In the filled case (-1): 131 states in the VB, one empty trap state mid-gap.

So, my interpretation is that the trap state moved into the valence band energy level rather than "band edges". The "dramatic shift" is nothing special if you compare it to other localized systems - such as atoms and ions in gaseous state - changing their charge by 1 elementary charge.

Bonus question: I was also surprised to see that a trap state with a
−2  charge had its level in the middle of the bandgap, suggesting that
it might be a trap for both electrons and holes, when simple coulombic
considerations (as well as others) clearly suggest that it should
preferentially be preferentially a hole trap.

The surprise here originates from being used to looking at density of state diagrams for homogeneous and dense solids. If you have a single trap, it implies it isn't sufficient any more because a test charge now must be much smaller than 1 elementary charge, in order not to interact with the other states while being trapped. An electron does not split, so this scenario isn't a real one.
To conclude, it is better to stick to the simple coulombic considerations for describing traps.

I am aware of the distinction between delocalized Bloch states and localized trap states, I think my question reflects it. But I don't really follow how you explain the dramatic level shift from those general considerations. Would you have any reference to back up the claim that it is normal for midgap trap levels to shift back to valence band when they capture a charge carrier? If it is solely due to a local change in charge density, why is only one of the two trap states being affected?

You are making it simple indeed, but I am not convinced by the arguments. The instability of atomic dianions seems very far remote from the problem at hand. It seems to me like this is more "handwaving common sense" than an answer grounded in solid state science. Your suggestion that it is normal for the trap state to get delocalized into the valence band as a hole gets trapped would mean that I should observe no local spin density on the trap (because one electron is lost as a hole and the other is delocalized). I do, however, observe a spin density coherent with one localized charge.

In our case, in the presence of a hole, the delocalized valence band level is the one that is occupied by an electron. The localized trap state is unoccupied (or filled by a hole as you prefer to phrase it). As mentioned in the question, the holes is localized on the trap. It is not delocalized. I am not sure why you thought that was the point of confusion.

I will rewrite my answer. It was indeed not clear.

I have rewritten my answer now.

you have completely changed the content, the ideas are not the same anymore, which makes this comment thread incomprehensible for future readers. I still do not think it constitutes an answer that adresses the specifics of the question. You are mostly saying in many words "it is so because it just happens to be so". You seem to be considering that an energy level shifting by over 1eV with occupation is perfectly natural, and that the new energy level being broadly distributed in the VB has no confusing implications. I'm sorry but I'm not convinced you understand the problem you're answering.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
